# Vim—make lines in a buffer enterable

Tags: vim

I wrote the following one-liner command.

```
command! -nargs=? Gfind execute "split | enew | cd `git-pwd` | read !git ls-files | grep " .  expand("<args>") . " " <bar>
```

(
`git-pwd` returns the current get repo's root or './'

```
#!/bin/bash
git-pwd() {
  local root=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>&1 )
  [[  "$root" == "" ]] && { echo "./" && return; }
  [[  "$root" == fatal:* ]] { echo "./" && return 1; }
  echo "$root"
}
[[ "$BASH_SOURCE" == "$0" ]] && git-pwd "$@"
```

)

It allows me to do `:Gfind regex` and a split window opens up with the list of files whose path/name matches the regex. That I can use for navigation with `gf`.

I wonder if there's an easy way to make the returned files in that window enterable like in `cwindow` or `NERDTree`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Alternatives

- Use `:Gedit` with completion abbreviated paths. e.g. `:Gedit f/b/b<tab>` which will expand to `:Gedit foo/bar/baz` (Requires [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive))
- Glob with `:Gedit`. e.g. `:Gedit **/baz<tab>`
- Use a fuzzy finder like [CtrlP.vim](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) to jump around your project.
- Use something like [projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) to build navigation commands for a well structured project.

There are low tech solutions that use `:find` and `'path'`:

```
set path=.,**
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
```

These are not mutually exclusive as you can use all these methods as each have their own pro's and con's. I personally use projectionist.vim as my main navigation method.

#### Answer to your question

I would imagine the best thing would be to use the QuickFix list. Your command would populate the quickfix list with the files matching your pattern and then you can use `:copen` to actually see the files and move between them or use `:cnext`/`:cprev` type commands to move between files.

Put the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
command! -nargs=? Gfind call s:gfind(<q-args>)

function! s:gfind(pat)
  let grepprg = &grepprg
  let errorformat = &errorformat
  let &grepprg = 'cd ' . shellescape(fugitive#repo().dir()) . ' && git ls-files | grep '
  let &errorformat = '%f'
  execute 'grep ' . a:pat
  cwindow
  let &grepprg = grepprg
  let &errorformat = errorformat
endfunction
```

Notes: I have not tested this code. It also uses fugitive.vim, but you can use your `git-cwd` trick if you rather. You may want to remove `cwindow` command to depending on your workflow.